# How to add class library project to Uno-Platform?

Tags: uno-platform

My goal is to add some c# code as a separate project to an existing solution of Uno-platform application.

I am using Visual Studio 2019. If I try to add a new project to the solution and use the Uno Platform Library template I get this compile error:

```
Error   XA5207  Could not find android.jar for API level 30. This means the Android SDK platform for API level 30 is not installed. Either install it in the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager...), or change the Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is installed.
```

The instructions are clear. However I aim to support lower API level - 29. But I fail to find a place where to change the Xamarin.Android API version. It is not possible to change it in the project properties - it's just not there.(in the original Uno-plaform Android project I did setup the API level to 29).

I suppose I use the right template for uno-platform. Where do I setup the API level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix that from Visual Studio double click on the library project so you can edit the Proj file.

In the `TargetFrameworks` look for `MonoAndroid11.0` and remove it.

[image]

Make sure your project `TargetFrameworks` includes `monoandroid10.0` since this is needed for **Android 10** (Api 29).

Hope this helps.-

Answer (score 1):

Just as an addition to @pinedax answer - you can target Android API level 30 while keeping support for lower APIs. The target version is the version you compile against, but the min supported version (found in Android project's properties) marks the lowest version of Android you tested against. The app will run fine on older versions as long as you don't use APIs which are completely new.